# Default Filter Over Highlight Visual Interaction in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I don't like how PowerBi defaults to "highlight" visual interaction.  Is there a way to make "filter" visual interaction the default?

Comment: Please show us some example on what you do not like and describe how you would like to have it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting in Power BI to change that. In Power BI desktop go to File->Options and settings->Options->CurrentFile->Report Settings.

There you will see "Change default visual interaction from cross highlighting to cross filtering option". Click it and restart PBI, it should work fine.

[image]